# Python UnicodeDecodeError exception

Tags: python, unicode, decode, python-unicode

```
txt = input("vilken textfil vill du använda?")
fil = open(txt,"r")

spelare=[]
resultat=[]
bästnamn=None
bästkast=0

for line in fil:

kolumn=line.split()
kolumn1=len(kolumn[1])
kolumn2=len(kolumn[2])
if len(kolumn)<5:
    mu=float(kolumn[1])
    sigma=float(kolumn[2])
    #print(mu,sigma)
    #kast=random.normalvariate(mu,sigma)
    #print(kast)

    for r in range(0,6):
        kast=random.normalvariate(mu,sigma)
        resultat.append(kast)

if max(resultat)>bästkast:
   bästkast=max(resultat)
   bästnamn=kolumn[0]

print("Segrare", bästnamn, "som stötte", bästkast, "meter")
```

When I running the program I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 85: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much and yes I have python 3. With the change as you sad to import the codecs, I now get another error insteed.

`ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

What sholud I do? any suggestions?

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError` at line 7 (`bästnamn`), because of: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers. How come you didn't encounter it?

Comment: @CristFati because this is presumably Python 3, where Unicode letter characters are accepted as identifiers: see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: Wow, thank you, I was looking at _Python2_ (that's the first that popped up), I didn't imagine that they would extend the identifier charset in 3.x.

Comment: About `max`, well, that’s a different question, so you should really go through the whole process of first trying hard to fix it yourself, and only then posting a question. But briefly, it means that somewhere you’re passing `max()` a sequence that’s empty. I recommend using some `print` calls to see what’s going on.

Comment: Stop removing your question, this is not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re reading your file as though it were encoded in ASCII, but it’s
not. Given the `0xc3` I would say it’s probably encoded in UTF-8.

So, you need to open it with UTF-8 encoding:

```
import codecs

fil = codecs.open(txt, "r", "utf-8")
```

This all assumes you’re using Python 3, in which strings are Unicode by
default. Since you had no problem with non-ASCII identifiers, that seems
like a safe assumption.

Comment: It's Python 3, so you can use the built-in `open(txt, encoding='utf8')`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you have to type English letters in order python be able to read it. so you need to change these variables:

```
bästnamn
bästkast
```

**Edit:** `max()` is to give a maximum of a list and in string case it will break it to letters and give you back the maximum letter in alphabet, like so:

```
myNumList = [1,2,4,5,8,50,10]`
print max(myNumList ) #result 50

myString = 'tree'
print max(myList) #result 't' 

myMixList = [1,2,4,'Apple','20']`
print max(myMixList) #result 'Apple'
```

**Note** it wont work on single `integer` you will get error, but you do have pass list to it.

your code is fine, just the document you are feeding to, might has some mistakes init, I see your application expect at least 4 column but never use the 4th column which the file type of it doesn't really matter, but i believe your document should be like so:

```
[String/number] [Number] [Number]
```

example of your document should be like so:

```
String1 158 212
String2 584 795
1234567 845 356
String4 356 489
String5 876 215
String6 985 853
String7 111 809
String8 234 058
```

**Note:** if you have string in second or third column that could cause the error, string can't convert to `float` as well as `random.normalvariate` wont take string.

Comment: Python 3 allows non-ASCII identifiers.

Comment: Thank you so much and yes I have python 3. With the change as you sad to import the codecs, I now get another error insteed.                    ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence.                                                                           What sholud I do? any suggestions?

Comment: @programming i expect the problem is cause by the document that feeding in to, i will edit my answer and explain that.